# A module over PID

Tags: ring-theory, modules, principal-ideal-domains, ring-homomorphism

Let *R* be a PID and *M* be a module over *R* ⋀ cyclic.
Then prove that ∀*N*⊂*M*; a submodule of *M*, *N* is cyclic.

[My idea]

∃*m*∈*M* s.t. *M*=*Rm* (∵*M* is cyclic)

*p*: *R*(= a module over *R*) → *M*, *p*(*a*) = *am*; module-hom ⋀ surjective.

Now, let ∀*N*⊂*M*; a submodule of *M* be fixed. I tried to use "theorem on homomorphisms of modules", but I don't have no idea about next:

--how use this theorem? (What is Ker(p), Im(p)? What should I divide R by?)
--When should I use assumption: R is PID ?

Show me the careful answer, please.

Comment: When you say "a module over R ⋀ cyclic", do you mean "a cyclic module over R"? Or that it is a module over R and a cyclic group? Or something else?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2259159/497335

Comment: @Arthur I think it means ''and'', the [logical conjunction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_conjunction).

Comment: @Arthur thank you for comment. I mean "M is a cyclic module over R."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $N$ be a submodule of $M=Rm$ and consider

$I:=\{r\in R : rm\in N\}$.

Then $I$ is an ideal of $R$ (check this). Hence $I=Rx$ for some $x\in R$. Consequently $N=Rxm$.